# SqlException catch the errors in schema

Tags: c#, sqlexception

Please any one help me of this errors happened on my work that make me crazy now. I would like to know that the schema element below it is correct or not, if not please help me solve that right the way. I used C# programming wrote the code to run it and when I used method `adapter.Fill(ds)` the output give an error like this:

> SqlException catch: syntax error near ","

```
<xs:appinfo>
  <wang:relation parent="n_person" parentKey="login" child="n_address" childKey="person_id"/>
  <wang:relation parent="n_org" parentKey="name" child="n_address" childKey="org_id"/>
  <wang:directive sql="SELECT street, city, province, postcode, sid, NULL FROM s_address,    
     s_student WHERE s_address.aid = s_student.fk_add;"/>
  <wang:directive sql="SELECT street, city, province, postcode, pid, NULL FROM s_address, 
     s_professor WHERE s_address.aid = s_professor.fk_add;"/>
  <wang:directive sql="SELECT street, city, province, postcode, NULL, name FROM s_address,  
     s_department WHERE s_address.aid = s_department.fk_add;"/>
</xs:appinfo>
```

Comment: somewhere where you are entering information externally, youre putting in a , without sanitising it in double quotes, so the sql command takes it as a , as it understands it, instead of a , the text value.

Answer (score 0):

Check your query statement in your query browser